# Why does scikit-learn smooth IDF by adding 1 to both the numerator and demominator?

Tags: tf-idf

Scikit-learn [says](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html):

> If smooth_idf=True (the default), the constant “1” is added to the numerator and denominator of the idf as if an extra document was seen containing every term in the collection exactly once, which prevents zero divisions: idf(t) = log [ (1 + n) / (1 + df(t)) ] + 1.

But by Laplace smoothing, shouldn't the smoothed term be
$$
idf(t) = \log \left[\frac{2 + n}{1 + df(t)} \right] + 1
$$

Here is a short derivation of the above. Let the probability that a term $t$ is in the document be $\pi$. Let $\pi$ follow a Beta distribution prior. So:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi &\sim Beta(\alpha, \beta) \\
df(t)|\pi & \sim Binom(n, \pi)
\end{aligned}
$$

The posteior of $\pi$ is
$$
\pi | df(t) \sim Beta(\alpha+df(t), \beta + n - df(t))
$$

The Bayes mean estimator of $\pi$ is
$$
\mathbb E[\pi] = \frac{df(t) + \alpha}{n + \alpha + \beta}
$$

If we assume a uniform prior, i.e. $\alpha=\beta=1$, we have:
$$
\mathbb E[\pi] = \frac{df(t) + 1}{n + 2}
$$

So the Laplace smoothing version of the idf is:
$$
idf(t) = \log \left[\frac{2 + n}{1 + df(t)} \right] + 1
$$

Comment: laplace smoothing is about adding one *a priori* "success" AND one *a priori* "failure". That is, your proposed smoothed term is equivalent to adding *two* documents, one with every word in the vocabulary in it once, and one completely empty. The scikit-learn approach is to simply add the former doc, i.e. the one with the complete vocabulary, but not the empty doc. In my view, there's no reason we would be able to say that scikit learn *should* be using Laplace's approach: either is a heuristic based on a judgement call.

Comment: (additionally, if I recall correctly, Laplace in developing the aforementioned smoothing is considering the probability that the sun rises tomorrow, e.g. a single binary event is considered. The situation is different in the TFiDF case, where we have a very, very large vocab of binary events. one might instead be tempted to modify Laplace's suggestion by adding $V$ many documents where $V$ is the vocab size, each a singleton containing a given word of the vocabuarly. This would be a significant modification to the original formula relative to sklearn's proposed smoothing.)

Comment: I agree that it may just be a heuristic-based judgment call. But if we were to do Laplace smoothing, it is +2 instead of +1. I added some derivations above.

Comment: did you mean beta instead of gamma for the $\pi$ prior? Regardless, the reason you're achieving this result is because you are considering each problem marginally, rather than jointly, which would lead to yet a different approach.

Comment: Oops. Yes, Beta instead of Gamma. Fixing it right now.